# systemctl commands won't work in an lxc container

Tags: systemd, nginx, lxc, container

I ssh into my container and I run this command:

```
systemctl restart nginx.service
```

And the terminal spits outs one of these bad boys:

```
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

Anybody encounter something like this? Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance, guys.

Notes:

- I'm using this container to mess with ansible 2
- the output of `uname -a` for the host is

  ```
  Linux your-homey 4.10.0-35-generic #39~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 13 09:02:42 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```
- the container is of an 'ubuntu' type.

Comment: Did you confirm systemd is running inside the container with something like `ps auxw | grep systemd` ?

Comment: @MarkStosberg I got:  

    `root        38  0.0  0.0  35276  3932 ?        Ss   15:22   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald`